# What is the correct jquery selector syntax?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jquery to aggregate all of the text in each anchor tag into a single message.  If it was working correctly, I would see an alert with this content:

> high_cases::pool_config::indy_pool_config_request_works_for_disabling_writing
>   high_cases::pool_restart::indy_pool_restart_request_works_for_start_cancel_works

I am currently seeing this error in the browser console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value
>       at Array.reduce ()
>       at copyAllTestNamesToClipboard

I do not have my jquery selector correct. What is the correct syntax?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function copyAllTestNamesToClipboard() {
        var array = new Array();

        $('div','a').each(function(){
            array.push($(this).html());
        });

        var message = array.reduce(function(pre, next) {
            return pre + '\n' + next;
        });

        alert(message);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link bnt-sm" onclick="copyAllTestNamesToClipboard()">(Copy)</button>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="error_group_collapse" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
  <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-body-header">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#t189_error_group_collapse">high_cases::pool_config::indy_pool_config_request_works_for_disabling_writing</a>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div id="t189_error_group_collapse" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <!-- other stuff -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body-header">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#t192_error_group_collapse">high_cases::pool_restart::indy_pool_restart_request_works_for_start_cancel_works</a>
        </div>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Also for note, I did not want to just select all anchor tags in the DOM as there could be additional anchor tags I do not want.  I only want the anchor tags in the div with `id="error_group_collapse"`.

Thnx for the help.

Comment: Well you did not set the initial value of pre in reduce...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you use `$('div','a')` <strike>which says 'give me *all* `div` and *all* `anchor` elements</strike>.

As pointed out in @RoryMcCrossan's comment below:

> The selector `$('div', 'a')` is looking for `div` elements which are children of an `a` element. It only selects those `div`, not both types of element.

You need to concatenate the element names in one string, to order the selector to give you all the anchor elements *in* the div element, and use the 'hash' selector (`#`) for an element with an id. If you really want `id="error_group_collapse"` to be the only element to fetch the anchor elements from, this is how you change it: `$('#error_group_collapse a')`.

(Note that I replaced your alert with the `console.log` command for demonstration purposes, of course you can just use your alert)

```js
function copyAllTestNamesToClipboard() {
  var array = new Array();

  $('#error_group_collapse a').each(function() {
    array.push($(this).html());
  });

  var message = array.reduce(function(pre, next) {
    return pre + '\n' + next;
  });

  console.log(message);
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link bnt-sm" onclick="copyAllTestNamesToClipboard()">(Copy)</button>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="error_group_collapse" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="panel-body-header">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#t189_error_group_collapse">high_cases::pool_config::indy_pool_config_request_works_for_disabling_writing</a>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div id="t189_error_group_collapse" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <!-- other stuff -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body-header">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#t192_error_group_collapse">high_cases::pool_restart::indy_pool_restart_request_works_for_start_cancel_works</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Currently you use $('div','a') which says 'give me all div and all anchor elements` Slight correction here; that selector is looking for `div` elements which are children of an `a` element. It only selects those `div`, not both types of element.

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan! I see I indeed made a slight mistake there. I will point to your (upvoted) comment in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the initial value in reduce

```
var message = array.reduce(function(pre, next) {
  return pre + '\n' + next;
}, ''); // <-- forgot that
```

But I am not sure why you are using reduce. Just use join.

```
var message = array.join('\n')
```

And you selector is wrong. It is looking for all the divs inside of the anchors. You probably want: `$('div a')`

The jQuery way would be map() and get() and join()

```
$('div a')
  .map(function () {
    return $(this).html();
  })
  .get()
  .join('\n')
```

Comment: Thnx.  I thought reduce was overkill but didn't know what other options there were for arrays.